# Url not rewritten by GKE load balancer provokes a 404 for non-root application urls

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

## Summary (Edit)

Below is very verbose, here is the short version: since the ingress load balancer of GKE controls the GCP http load balancer, and after taking a look at [GCP Load Balancing (non classic) - URL rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74219945/gcp-load-balancing-non-classic-url-rewrite) , is it possible to control and add the following part in the http load balancer configuration only by editing the configuration of GKE ingress load balancer?

```
  routeAction:
    urlRewrite:
      pathPrefixRewrite: /
```

Editing only the http load balancer is not viable since every time the GKE ingress is edited it will overwrite the http load balancer configuration.

## Original post, more detailed

I have two web applications running on kubrnetes, each exposed with a clusterIP, each exposed by the same cluster IP. The kubernetes is in fact hosted on Google cloud Platform (GKE) :

In the ingress configuration I have written the following routes :

- The first application is exposed on route / (http://example.net/)
- The second application is exposed on route /doc (http://example.net/doc)

The first application can be used correctly, but the second application exposes a 404 error: `[error] 8#8: *18598 "/usr/share/nginx/html/doc/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 100.105.10.12, server: localhost, request: "GET /doc/ HTTP/1.1", host: "example.net"`.

How I understand it is that the load balancer correctly redirect the /doc url to the second application, but the applications looks for `/usr/share/nginx/html/doc/index.html` instead of the `/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`, because of the /doc string in the url. How do I make my doc application to ignore the /doc part of the url ?

The Doc application Dockerfile (its really a documentation application written with Sphinx, nothing more than html/css/jpg files with no javascript) :

```
FROM blabla.artifactory.mycompany.net/nginx:latest
COPY ./doc/html/ /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Load balancer yaml configuration:

The `ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /` does not seem to work either.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: '"k8s1-4060bfed-default-doc-mmmp5-80-f2598458":"HEALTHY","k8s1-4060bfed-default-stack-8czp2-80-50d87c46":"HEALTHY","k8s1-4060bfed-kube-system-default-http-backend-80-45d2eb1e":"HEALTHY"}'
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: k8s2-fs-bf0cgmfe-default-myapp-internal-lb-i6whgm2h
    ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy: k8s2-ts-bf0cgmfe-default-myapp-internal-lb-i6whgm2h
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: k8s2-cr-bf0cgmfe-al3xil887kkuii29-b6ff44ace1c3314a
    ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-bf0cgmfe-default-myapp-internal-lb-i6whgm2h
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "false"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: gce-internal
    kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: myapp-internal-load-balancer
  creationTimestamp: "2023-12-05T15:22:59Z"
  finalizers:
  - networking.gke.io/ingress-finalizer-V2
  generation: 24
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          f:ingress.kubernetes.io/backends: {}
          f:ingress.kubernetes.io/https-forwarding-rule: {}
          f:ingress.kubernetes.io/https-target-proxy: {}
          f:ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-cert: {}
          f:ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: {}
        f:finalizers:
          .: {}
          v:"networking.gke.io/ingress-finalizer-V2": {}
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: glbc
    operation: Update
    subresource: status
    time: "2023-12-13T12:59:00Z"
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: {}
          f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
          f:kubernetes.io/ingress.regional-static-ip-name: {}
      f:spec:
        f:rules: {}
        f:tls: {}
    manager: GoogleCloudConsole
    operation: Update
    time: "2023-12-13T15:21:24Z"
  name: myapp-internal-lb
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "14500796"
  uid: c125a9be-0eed-452b-b9fc-3ed31e8c970f
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.net
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: stack-8czp2
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: doc-mmmp5
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /doc
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - secretName: self-example-net
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 100.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

GKE Ingress does not support URL rewrites.   But you can use the [GKE Gateway API](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways#configure_url_rewrites) (preferred now in any case) to accomplish this.

You'd have two HTTPRoutes (one for each backend web application).  For the rewrite for the "doc" app, your HTTPRoute would look something like:

```
  apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
  kind: HTTPRoute
  metadata:
    name: www
  spec:
    parentRefs:
      - kind: Gateway
        name: external-http
    rules:
    - matches:
      - path:
          type: PathPrefix
          value: /doc
      filters:
      - type: URLRewrite
        urlRewrite:
          hostname: example.net
          path:
            type: ReplacePrefixMatch
            replacePrefixMatch: /
      backendRefs:
      - name: doc-mmmp5
        port: 80
```

(Note:  this assumes you have already [deployed a Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways#external-gateway) named "external-http" but you can deploy your own Gateway using any name you like)